# Duplicate transaction under same transaction ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am having an issue tracking my transactions via Tag Manager.
I have a GA Universal Analytics Transaction tag which fires on transaction completes. All cool until here.

So I have added another tag to be able to record Checkout behaviour but suddenly I am getting double transactions for a single transaction ID.

Can an event populate the actual transactions in the Acquisition > Source/Medium data table? This second tag is an Event tag actually, so it confuses me a bit.

[image: Tag to push Checkout data for EE Checkout behaviour]

Answer (score 0):

Sure (actually for some scenarios sending e-commerce events is even considered best practice, e.g. for product list tracking).

However this would send a transaction only when a purchase action is specified in your e-commerce variable (the one you specify in the E-commerce section in "Read data from Variable"). Unless this contains a purchase event your problem is probably elsewhere.

GA does not deduplicate transactions, so even a reload can potentially cause double transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Is the screenshot you included of the second tag? If so, you'll likely want to remove or modify the ecommerce setting from that tag as GTM will populate the ecommerce reports with whatever data is in the EE Funnel Step 4 variable, even if it's the same data that has already been sent in a previous ecommerce beacon. So if EE Funnel Step 4 is sending an ecommerce purchase action and the same transaction id as your previous ecommerce beacon it would be counted twice in GA.